# How to modify a org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented Specification in by @RestController to set values in Specificaton object.

```
public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> searchUnexpectedLikelyToChurn(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
            @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10, sort = "buyer", direction = Direction.ASC) Pageable pageable, 
            @Conjunction(value = {
                    @Or({           
                        @Spec(path="buyer", params="search", spec=LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                        @Spec(path = "email", params = "search", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                        @Spec(path = "shipCity", params = "search", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                        @Spec(path = "shipState", params = "search", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                        @Spec(path = "country", params = "search", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class)
                    })}, and = @Spec(path = "company",params = "company", spec = Equal.class)) Specification<CustomerEntity> customerSpec
```

And I have used this library [https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver#enabling-spec-annotations-in-your-spring-app].

Now I need to add another condition on this Specification object, and is a java.util.Date object which is calculated on code rather than user input. How can I add this ?

My current DAO implementation is :

```
 @Repository
public interface CustomerDao extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CustomerEntity> { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification` interface as follows:

```
Specification combinedSpec - Specification.where(customerSpec)
                                          .and(calculateAdditionalSpec());
```

Use `Specifications` helper class if you use older version of Spring Data JPA.